# Change GUI on runtime with threads C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-interface

I'm trying to make a serverpanel that check if my three servers are online.
If got 3 remote servers running and want to know if they are online.
What i'm trying to do is three threads that are checking the status of 1 server and act on the result.

```
class ServerChecker
{
    private byte firstIP, secondIP, thirthIP, fourthIP;
    private string message;
    private Boolean status;
    private Ping ping = new Ping();
    //Zet de waardes van de IP gelijk aan die van de class. En gaat daarna de server pingen.
    public Boolean checkConnection(byte first, byte second, byte thirth, byte fourth)
    {
        this.firstIP = first;
        this.secondIP = second;
        this.thirthIP = thirth;
        this.fourthIP = fourth;
        return connection();

    }
    //Stuurt een Ping naar de server en bekijkt de response en reageert op de response
    private Boolean connection()
    {
        PingReply reply;
        try
        {
            reply = ping.Send(new IPAddress(new byte[] { firstIP, secondIP, thirthIP, fourthIP }), 3000);
            //Als er een correct response is server online
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                this.status = true;
                this.message = "    De Server is online...";
            }
            //Als er een incorrecte response is server offline
            else
            {
                this.status = false;
                this.message = "    De Server is Offline...";
            }
        }
        //Als er iets fout gaat vang de fout op en geef een message.
        catch (Exception)
        {
            this.status = false;
            this.message = "    Er is iets Fout gegaan";
        }
        return this.status;
    }
    public string getMessage()
    {
        return this.message;
    }
}
```

This is my Form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
namespace Server.ProgramForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Image WebsiteServerImage,DatabaseServerImage,ApplicatieServerImage,WebsiteImage,DatabaseImage,ApplicatieImage;
        private Engine.ThreadHandler thread;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeImages();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              this.WebsiteServer_Image.Image = WebsiteServerImage;
              this.DatabaseServer_Image.Image = DatabaseServerImage;
              this.ApplicatieServer_Image.Image = ApplicatieServerImage;
        }

        private void InitializeImages()
        {
            setWebsiteServerImageDisabled();
            setDatabaseServerImageDisabled();
            setApplicatieServerImageDisabled();
        }
        public void setWebsiteServerImage(Boolean Status)
        {
                switch (Status)
                {
                    case true: WebsiteServer_Image.Image = global::Server.Properties.Resources.web_online;
                        break;
                    case false: WebsiteServer_Image.Image = global::Server.Properties.Resources.web_offline;
                        break;
                }
        }

        public void setWebsiteServerImageDisabled()
        {
            WebsiteServerImage = global::Server.Properties.Resources.web_error;
        }

        public void setDatabaseServerImage(Boolean Status)
        {
            switch (Status)
            {
                case true: DatabaseServerImage = global::Server.Properties.Resources.db_online;
                    break;
                case false: DatabaseServerImage = global::Server.Properties.Resources.db_offline;
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void setDatabaseServerImageDisabled()
        {
            DatabaseServerImage = global::Server.Properties.Resources.db_error;
        }

        public void setApplicatieServerImage(Boolean Status)
        {
            switch (Status)
            {
                case true: ApplicatieServerImage = global::Server.Properties.Resources.dev_online;
                    break;
                case false: ApplicatieServerImage = global::Server.Properties.Resources.dev_offline;
                    break;
            }
        }
        public void setApplicatieServerImageDisabled()
        {
            ApplicatieServerImage = global::Server.Properties.Resources.dev_error;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my program(main)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
namespace Server.Engine
{
    class Program
    {
        private static ProgramForm.Form1 form = new ProgramForm.Form1();
        private static ThreadHandler thread;
        private static Boolean websiteStatus;
        public static void Main()
        {
            //Start eerst de Threads voordat je Form laat zien
            thread = new ThreadHandler(form);
            thread.startWebsiteThread();
            thread.startDatabaseThread();
            form.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

ThreadHandler class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Server.Engine
{
    class ThreadHandler
    {
        private Thread DatabaseServerThread,ApplicatieServerThread,WebsiteServerThread;
        private Checkers.ServerChecker ServerChecker=new Checkers.ServerChecker();
        private ProgramForm.Form1 form;
        private Boolean DatabaseServerStatus, WebsiteServerStatus, ApplicatieServerStatus;
        private System.Threading.Timer DatabaseServerTimer;
        //Constructor
        public ThreadHandler(ProgramForm.Form1 temp)
        {
            this.form = temp;
        }
        //Start de DatabaseServer Thread
        public void startDatabaseThread()
        {
            this.DatabaseServerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DatabaseThreadHandling));
            this.DatabaseServerThread.Start();
        }
        //Regelt de handelingen van de Database Thread
        private void DatabaseThreadHandling()
        {
                if (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() == true)
                {
                    //Geeft true terug als de ping slaagd.
                    this.DatabaseServerStatus = ServerChecker.checkConnection(145, 24, 222, 103);
                    form.setDatabaseServerImage(this.DatabaseServerStatus);
                }
                else
                {
                    form.setDatabaseServerImageDisabled();
                }

        }
        //Start de WebsiteServer Thread
        public void startWebsiteThread()
        {
            this.WebsiteServerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WebsiteThreadHandling));
            this.WebsiteServerThread.Start();
        }
        private void WebsiteThreadHandling()
        {
                if (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() == true)
                {
                    //Geeft true terug als de ping slaagd.
                    this.WebsiteServerStatus = ServerChecker.checkConnection(145, 24, 222, 118);
                    form.setWebsiteServerImage(this.WebsiteServerStatus);
                }
                else
                {
                    form.setWebsiteServerImageDisabled();
                }
        }
        //Start de ApplicatieServer Thread
        public void startApplicatieThread()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that this will only update my UI ones. And it will not change.
I'm out of idea's to solve the problem. I tryed to run the code without the treads on my UI thread but that is a worse idea and it gives the UI a mayor lagg.
What i trying to do is. When a serverChange is happend. Change the Image and Label from online to offline. But i want to run the process to check the status of the server on a other thread(3 total). When i trying to change to pictures i get a error that i cant change controls on a other thread.
With the code i posted it only run ones..
Someone got a brilliant idea how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
form.Invoke(new Action(() => label.Text = "offline"));
```

Or something to that effect

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I created a timer in the form_load and create a repaint function.
I set the Controls to a variable like this.
This.picturebox.Image = tempImage
where tempImage is type of Image.
I change the tempImage from a other thread without letting the thread directly change the controller.
If u want a sample you can always leave a message